# Looping through query results multiple times with mysqli_fetch_array?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Does the `mysqli_fetch_array()` function remove each value as it returns it? If not, how can I go back to the top of the array when I've finished looping through it?

I need to loop through the list several times, as I'm using it to generate unique usernames (by adding numbers to the end if it's already taken).

```
$uniqueName = true;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($namesList)) {
    if ($row['Username'] == $UserBase) {
        $uniqueName = false;
    }
}

$number = 0;
if ($uniqueName == true) {
    $User = $UserBase;
}
else {
    while ($uniqueName == false) {
        $uniqueName = true;
        $number++;
        $tempList = $namesList2;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tempList)) {
            if ($row['Username'] == $UserBase . $number) {
                $uniqueName = false;
            }
        }
    }
    $User = $UserBase . $number;
}
```

`$namesList` is a list of all usernames in the database so far. Basically, `$UserBase` is the forename and surname of the user added together. What happens at the moment is that `$User` becomes `$Userbase` with a `1` on the end, even when it should be 2. However, if it's the first instance of the name then it doesn't add anything (which is working as intended).

Answer (score 7):

You could use the mysqli_fetch_all function to return all results as an array, which you could then manipulate as you would any other array in PHP:

```
$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($namesList, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

note that by default `mysqli_fetch_all()` returns enumerated rows, as in `mysqli_fetch_row()`, and if you need associative arrays, you need to add `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as a parameter.