# PHP MySQLi Passing text value of select or querying for it

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a USERS table that stores both User ID's (users.uid) and a full name (users.full_name).   Then I have an On Call schedule table that lists all weeks for the next year along with the a name field and user id (uid) field for each on-call shift slot (say day & night).    The on call

> on_call_week,us_night_uid,us_night_full_nam,us_day_uid,us_day_full_name
>
> 17-12-25, 53, Jane Doe, 94, Jill Todd17-12-18, 2342, John Smith, 24, Bob Orr

I then have a form that lists all on call week start dates (with check boxes next to them) and a submit button on that goes to a page that lists a form with every selected on call week with drop downs both on call slots (day night)

What I'm trying to figure out his how to update both the UID field and the full_name field when only the value of the drop down list boxes is passed (the value being the UID's and the text being the full_names).

Should I be trying (in some way) to pass the text of the select drop downs?  If not should I just make a two new queries inside the FOR loop to grab the day and night slot full_names for each UID.   Or, should I be trying to do something like querying the whole user table into an array and then looping through that array twice per FOR loop pass to get the matching names for the two UID slots?

One thing I don't understand about MySQLi that I'm having trouble finding an answer for is if you loop through a mysqli_fetch_array multiple times, does the query get remade or can you loop through the $result multiple times without the query being remade to the db (while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) )?   I'm still pretty new to PHP and honestly not even sure how to visually see how many times PHP queries a database verses using a temporary copy(?) of the result set.

I was following this [old guide](http://www.vasplus.info/tutorial/155/update-or-delete-multiple-rows-using-php) on how to build a form for updating more than one record at a time based on which records are checked.

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
$dbname = "on_call";
include '../shared_recources/db_connect.php'; 

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && trim($_POST["submit"]) != "") 
{
    $checked_weeks = count($_POST["selected_on_call_weeks"]);

    for($i=0; $i<$checked_weeks; $i++) 
    {
        $us_day_uid = $_POST["us_day_uid"][$i];
        $us_night_uid = ($_POST["us_night_uid"][$i];

        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE on_call.on_call_schedule
                            SET us_day_full_name = '" . $_POST["us_day_full_name"][$i] . "',
                                us_day_uid = '?????????',                           
                                us_night_full_name = '"  . $_POST["us_night_full_name"][$i] . "',
                                us_night_uid = '"  '???????????????' . "',
                                WHERE id = '"  . $_POST["selected_on_call_weeks"][$i] . "' 

                            ");                 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is example of PHP code with SQL injection. Always use "mysqli_real_escape_string" function on each variable passed to database, ex. mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['variable']) ( http://php.net/manual/pl/mysqli.real-escape-string.php )

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Executes query only one time and then loop through results which can be stored in PHP machine RAM or on database server - you can't controll where it's stored, it depends on database 'php driver'.

---

Rest of your question is quite hard to understand. You must wait for someone else to give you full answer.
It would be much easier to understand, if you add SQL schema (tables schema) to your question.

Comment: Thank you.  One thing I really was trying to understand is if for each "WHILE($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))" loop the query is re-run to the database.    If that actually does cause the query to be re-made to the database, that could result in the form UPDATE action causing dozens of queries to go off.     I'm still not clear on that - if each WHILE loop against the mysqli_fetch_array causes a new query to go off or if (after the first time) PHP is working off a stored array of the value (in memory?)?

Comment: Or more simpler said would be:   How do you loop through a mysqli_fetch_array multiple times without the query being remade to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The query is being executed on the DB each time [mysqli_query] is run.

To get a better feel for what's going on I suggest A) comment-out the [mysqli_query] so it's not hitting the database then B) build a string variable within your [for] of the SQL query.
You can then echo the finished query to the screen after the [for] loop. This will let you know exactly what you will be sending to the DB.

After you review the behavior, and it's as you expect it, you can un-comment your [mysqli_query] and adjust it as needed -OR- you could run the [mysqli_query] outside the [for] loop (where you echo the variable).

Here is some more detail from PHP.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Thanks!   I think what I was really looking for was just the concept of moving the whole result set into a multi-dimensional array so the result said can be used (searched) multiple times.   I think this answer is really what I need:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565844/looping-through-query-results-multiple-times-with-mysqli-fetch-array